# Delete image from database using ajax and php

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to delete images using ajax. It's showing the alert message that the data has been deleted but in the table the record is there. How can I delete the image record from the table....

```
<span><input type="submit" id="del_btn" value="Delete Image" /></span>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input#del_btn").click(function(){
         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "del.php", // 
             data: {id: <?php echo $delid; ?>},
             success: function(msg){
             alert("Image Deleted from database");  
             },
             error: function(){
             alert("failure");
           }
           });
        });
    });
  </script>
```

and this is del.php

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
    $imgid = $_POST['id'];
    $con=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=newimg","root","");
    $sql = "DELETE FROM attempt010 WHERE id='$imgid' ";
    $con->execute($sql);
}
?>
```

Comment: Your delete query is open for injection, please use binding (that is: prepare it properly). See; http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Comment: Sorry I'm new here, I wasn't aware of that ... I'll keep it in mind

Comment: @ARIJITDASGUPTA You can still accept the answer on that other question. Go to it, scroll to the answer, click the check mark (assuming it answered your question, based on the comments it did)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PDO `execute` function executes a prepared statement. So you need to prepare **then** execute. Also prepared statements should be parameterized. Try:

```
if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
    $imgid = $_POST['id'];
    $con=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=newimg","root","");
    $sql = "DELETE FROM attempt010 WHERE id=?";
    $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array($imgid));
}
```

For more information see:

1. http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php
2. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php
3. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: It's working thank you @chris85.. How can I delete the preview of the image?

Comment: I don't know, what's a preview? Do you mean remove it on the page that the AJAX was sent from?

Comment: yes.. I mean in that page I've fetched the uploaded images.. in that I've created that delete button to delete the record from the db.. I wnt to delete the preview also... @chris

Comment: Instead of `alert("Image Deleted from database");` do something like `$('#image').attr('display', 'none');` or similar.  This is a JS/CSS question/issue, not PHP.